# one solution to bug .innerHTML IE8

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I attempt to fix a bug in IE8 that erases the white space in an element when I use innerHTML

one example in html:

**Association football** is a

```
<b>
   <span >Association football</span>
</b>
<span>
    is a 
</span>
```

when I do this in javascript:

```
spans=document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for (var i=0;i<spans.length; i++){
  spans[i].outerHTML = spans[i].innerHTML;
}
```

the results are

**Association football**is a

and I need that it not remove the whitespace

> **ball** is

Comment: What is the bug, and what are you asking? Do you want to remove spaces between elements, or remove all spaces?

Comment: This is not a bug, read the JS Docs carefully please :-\

Comment: JS Docs  not mention any of this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.outerhtml(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: If you don't want to be removed the whitespace, you can use **&nbsp;** instead of the whitespace.

Comment: mmmm.. use &nbsp, yes it is the ultimate solution that I can take ¿more solutions?

Comment: @Martin You can use **margin-left** as another solution at span of **ball is**.

Comment: yes but not all my span required separation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug and you can see that http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228